# Knockout JS - array replace whilst keeping the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This is an interesting one, wondering if anyone out there has thought the same or has implemented it.

My scenario:

I've got an observable array which, on first load, I want to create a bunch of `<div>` tags. Easy enough, Knockout does this for me. However, after a button is clicked, I want to load another set of results into the *same* `<div>` elements instead of re-render them (Knockout default behaviour by the looks of things).

Such as:

```
function viewModel() {
     var self = this;

    self.testArray = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.loadMore = function () {
       var length = self.testArray().length;

       if (length > 0) {
          console.log('loading into divs');
          // Load into original <div>'s
          // This is deleting the old <div>'s from the DOM and creating new ones...
          // How can I just replace the original <div> content for performance gains?
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                   self.testArray.replace(self.testArray()[i], new { text: 'New Text' });
            }
      }
      else {
           // Create the <div>'s by pushing items to the array
           for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                self.testArray.push(ko.observable(new { text: 'New Text' }));
           }
      }
   };
}

var model = new viewModel();
model.loadMore();
ko.applyBindings(model);

<!-- ko foreach: testArray -->
      <div data-bind="text: text"></div>
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: loadMore">Next</button>
```

A bit easier to understand...

** first load **

```
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
```

** second load **

```
<div></div> - deleted
<div></div> - deleted
<div></div> - deleted
<div></div> - deleted
<div></div> - deleted
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
<div></div> - created
```

What I want on second load...

```
<div></div> - edited
<div></div> - edited
<div></div> - edited
<div></div> - edited
<div></div> - edited
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to do it for performance gains, instead of re-creating `<div>`'s in the DOM, I want simply to just re-use the ones that are there.

Answer (score 3):

Knockout's `foreach` logic would not know that your new item has the same contents as your current item.

If you kept the same data objects, used an observable for your `text` property, then just updated the `text` on an existing item, the elements would be kept and the element's innerText/textContent would be updated.

So, you would want to use observables for any properties that change.

Comment: Aha, excellent idea. Then the objects would change rather than their surrounding <div> elements. Thank you.